# Wildfly 9.x fails encoding greek attachment filenames

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, wildfly, wildfly-9

I am using  `javax.mail` to call a mail server and send a file as a mail attachment  encoding the file name like this:`MimeUtility.encodeText(filename,"UTF-8",null)`

While this has been working fine on `WildFly 8`, it fails on `WildFly 9.x` with the **same** **mail** server. What I mean is that the attachment description is received in this format : `=UTF-8BzrTOv866zrnOvM63IM68zrUgzrXOu867zrfOvc65zrrOsS5wZGY==`

I have been trying to:

1) Find a relative setting on the application server - no luck.

2) Encode with `ISO-8859-7` which only works occasionally since it seems to depend on the filename length and the presence of some characters.

3) Find a relative setting on the client (microsoft outlook) which i suppose misses some info to decode successfully.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hello. Have you managed to solve this issue? I'm am facing the exact same problem. Thank you.

Comment: @GGrec The original question says "it fails on WildFly 9". What does this mean? To me it is not completely clear what and **where** goes wrong. It might be also useful to know what settings are used for the `file.encoding` system property and servlet encoding.

Comment: Have you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674972/5934435 ?

Comment: Try using MimeUtility.encodeText(filename,"UTF-8","B")

Comment: @ZaheerBaloch That doesn't work either. I ended up stripping character accents, which is a temporary solution.

Comment: @GGrec I think you don't need to manually `encodeText`, it should be handled by Java Mail API.

Answer (score 0):

To test your issue I created a demo project [here](https://github.com/tsabirgaliev/mail-test). It sends a messages with non-ascii symbols in various parts, but doesn't use `encodeText`, as it is automatically handled by Mail API. I tested it with Wildfly 8, 9, 10 to send messages to http://mailtrap.io.

The first screen shows the message sent from Wildfly 8. The attachment is not sent properly, so it is absent:

[image: Attachment is not properly sent in Wildfly 8]

The second screen is a messages sent by Wildfly 9 (the same for 10). As you can see, there is an attachment with a proper filename:

[image: For Wildfly 9 and 10 all right!]

So what could be the issue here?

- Wildfly 8 ships with Java Mail API 1.5.1
- Wildfly 9 ships with Java Mail API 1.5.3
- Wildfly 10 ships with Java Mail API 1.5.5

I think you are experiencing a bug in Java Mail version 1.5.1.

Most probably, you worked around that bug when coded against Wildfly 8 (manually using `encodeText`), now that workaround is causing you problems.

Comment: I removed the workaround. We are using WF 10. Apparently, on some machines it works fine, while on other it replaces special character with a question mark, or even the whole filename with "noname". Can there be a machine-dependent setting?

Comment: @GGrec probably, you should specify default encoding for java: `bin/standalone.sh -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: @GGrec I'm sorry, the above comment is wrong :(, instead you should tweak `bin/standalone.conf`: `JAVA_OPTS=".... -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"`

Comment: @GGrec what are your findings? Any difference after setting default encoding?

Comment: I ended up stripping accents as a second workaround. Will try your suggestion, though.