# Wildfly 10.1.0 ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator

Tags: maven, jboss, jakarta-mail, wildfly-10, classnotfound

Creating instance of org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail the following problem occures:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
    at mypackage.MyClass.sendMail(MyClass.java:123)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator from [Module "org.apache.commons:main" from local module loader @5a4041cc (finder: local module finder @15b3e5b (roots: C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules,C:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
```

pom.xml contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\org\apache\commons\main\commons-email-1.3.3.jar\org\apache\commons\mail\MultiPartEmail.class exists and jboss-deployment-structure.xml contains:

```
<module name="org.apache.commons" />
<system export="true">
  <paths>
    <path name="javax/api"/>
    <path name="javax/activation/api"/>
    <path name="javax/mail/api"/>
  </paths>
</system>
```

Comment: Which version of Wildfly? Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650024/wildfly-9-javax-mail-is-not-working

Comment: You shouldn't need to include those paths at all in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml. Also the `javax.activation.api` module should already be included as a dependency on your deployment with the `javaee.api` module. Do you have any module exclusions in your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`?

Comment: @jamesr  am using Wildfly 10.1.0. There is no module exclusions in jboss-deployment-structure.xml. Thanks for the answer after reading it, I have studied again the [Implicit module dependencies for deployments] (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments) and modules\system\layers\base\javax\api\main\module.xml  and have understood why there is no need to include those javax/* paths in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins The wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\org\apache\commons\main\module.xml was created long time ago and have not been suspected, but was missing the javax.activation.api and javax.mail.api dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: Without `<scope>provided</scope>` the same problem occures.

Comment: Sorry, I have not noticed that the commons-email dependency occured 2 times in the pom.xml. Removing `<scope>provided</scope>` solved the problem. The wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\org\apache\commons\main\module.xml was created long time ago and have not been suspected, but was missing the javax.activation.api and javax.mail.api dependencies.